# Magento 1.9.3.1 Innoext Advanced Store Pricing (Version: 1.2.1.0) Module Product Price indexing issue Unknown column 'cwd.date' in 'field list'

Tags: magento1.9.3, magento1.9.3.1

When I tried to Integrate Innoext_AdvancedStorePricing Module in Magento 1.9.3.1 and tried to reindex the Product Prices, it failed with an error message:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'cwd.date' in 'field list', query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_index_price_final_idx` SELECT `e`.`entity_id`, `cg`.`customer_group_id`, `cw`.`website_id`, IF(IFNULL(tas_tax_class_id.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_tax_class_id.value, tad_tax_class_id.value) AS `tax_class_id`, IF(IFNULL(tas_price.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_price.value, tad_price.value) AS `orig_price`, IF(IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value) IS NUL ......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The issue:**

In the helper Innoexts_InnoCore_Helper_Version class (app/code/local/Innoexts/InnoCore/Helper/Version.php), there is a method to check whether the current version is an enterprise version:

```
protected function getEEMinVersion()
{
    return '1.9.2.5';
}
```

This should be the latest available version of Magento community, otherwise the method call `$this->isEE()` will return a true in magento 1.9.3.1 in below method.

```
public function isGe1600()
{
     return (($this->isGe('1.6.0.0') && !$this->isEE()) || ($this->isGe('1.11.0.0') && $this->isEE()));
}
```

**Solution:**
The ideal Solution is Innoext (now called as Merchantprotocol) should fix this to accommodate latest magento module versions as well.

The Quick solution is to change the version to something like below and wait for the provider to fix this issue:

```
protected function getEEMinVersion()
{
    return '1.9.9.9';
}
```